# why all the products are displayed with same description value?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

When I entered value in the description attribute to get displayed in product details page, same description of one particular product is getting displayed for all the products.Am stuck here figuring out what the problem may be. Someone kindly Help to resolve this priority issue.

Comment: I would suggest you to check description attribute value in database. If is not unique than you can find if any module that is caching

Comment: is the description of product X displayed in the product view page of product Y? or is it that this description is displayed for all products in a category view page ?

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis the description of product x is displayed for all the products.

Comment: @ Bhupendra Jadeja How to find if any other module is caching that?

Comment: Sure, but where? Product view or Category view?

Comment: product view page.